# Scope of Submit Button and calling a function

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, scope, submit

The code I'm working with is quite long, so I will paraphrase my problem.

The code I'm working with looks (roughly) like this:

```
<html><HEAD><meta http-equiv='Cache-control' content='no-cache'><meta http-      equiv='Expires' content='-1'>
<script>
function sendRequestXML()
{
  function asgn()
  {
    alert("!");
  }
document.write("<input type='submit' value='Submit Survey' onclick='asgn()' />
</script>
<body onload="sendRequestXML()">
<h4><u>EAM fetching data....</u></h4>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue I'm having is that I cannot call the asgn function with the button onclick. I think this has something to do with it being out of scope for the button. The error I keep getting is that "asgn is undefined or not a function object". How can I make the button and the function in the same scope?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script>
  window.asgn = function() {
    alert("!")
  }
</script>
```

This will make the function available globally.

A better alternative (as it does not need 'onclick=...') would be:

```
<script>
  document.querySelector("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("!")
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be like this for button to work

```
<html><HEAD><meta http-equiv='Cache-control' content='no-cache'><meta http-      equiv='Expires' content='-1'>
<script>
function sendRequestXML()
{


document.write("<input type='submit' value='Submit Survey' onclick='asgn()' />");
}

function asgn()
  {
    alert("!");
  }
</script>
<body onload="sendRequestXML()">
<h4><u>EAM fetching data....</u></h4>
</body>
</html>
```